# how to get the group commit offset from kafka(0.10.x)

Tags: apache-kafka

The offsets informations of the group were stored in zookeeper before. Now, in the Kafka Cluster (0.10.x), the offsets informations are stored in the topic which's name is `__consumer_offsets`.

But how could I get the offsets information of the group which I specified？

Comment: Btw: this is a know bug and there is already a PR for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3853

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For active groups, invoke command below to retrieve the offsets:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --describe --group test-consumer-group
```

For inactive groups, first get the target offset topic partition number by calculating Math.abs(groupId.hashCode()) % 50, then invoke:

```
bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --topic __consumer_offsets --partition <calculated number> --broker-list broker1:9092 --formatter "kafka.coordinator.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
```

to find offsets for the groups.

Comment: The script of `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` can only get the information which stored in zookeeper, but the offset information is only storing in the topic.

Comment: Not exactly. When specifying '--bootstrap-server', it checks the offset topic. Specifying '--zookeeper' means old consumer.

Comment: It works, thanks. The reason that I failed is because the cluster I used starts the security authentication, the script of `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` does not make corresponding change.

Comment: I found the `--all-groups` option to `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` to be very useful. It also shows inactive groups.