# Strange output from kafka-consumer-groups.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have a consumer group called myconsumergroup which appears when running:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --list
> myconsumergroup
```

I'm very sure I commited an offset. I would expect that this offset could be retrieved by running this command:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --group myconsumergroup
```

But instead I get this confusing output:

```
No topic available for consumer group provided
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
```

Can anybody explain why I don't retrieve the current offset for myconsumergroup?

NB: For further info I created my consumer in my NodeJS application like this:

```
new Consumer(
        client,
        [
          {topic}
        ],
        {
          groupId:'myconsumergroup'
        }
      )
```

And the Kafka client is created like this:

```
const client = new kafkanode.Client('localhost:2181', 'myservice');
```

Comment: Do you use new consumer or old consumer?

Comment: @amethystic I added info to my question.

Comment: Did you specify zookeeper connection info or broker list in NodeJS application?

Comment: I added more details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the group commit offset from kafka(0.10.x)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097126/how-to-get-the-group-commit-offset-from-kafka0-10-x)

Comment: Seems you are using a low-level API since kafka-node offers two consumers including Consumer.js and HighLevelConsumer.js. For the low-level API, there is no such group concept. Could you try to use HighLevelConsumer and then retry?

Comment: Thx for the tip @amethystic. I see that kafka-node actually offers a third alternative called ConsumerGroup. So which of these three: Consumer, HighLevelConsumer and ConsumerGroup, would you recommend to work with?